# video chat. red5 faster/needed?? why not just p2p?

Tags: p2p, red5, flash-media-server, videochat

Pardon my ignorance, but I am researching making a video chatroom, and what I am finding just seems really counter intuitive to me.  From what I have read, it sounds like the standard is for each user to stream their video to a media server, like red5, and then the server sends the stream to the other person.  Intuitively it seems like this just adds a middle man that would add lag to the video streaming because it has to go to a server, then turn around and go to a person, rather then just directly to a person.  Why not just p2p with something like adobe status/Cirrus?  Just use the service to get the other users ip, and then stream them your video directly?  Yet, it seems like almost everyone uses an FMS like red5..

What am I failing to understand here? What is the advantage of having this "middle man"?

Answer (score 1):

It would require lots of bandwidth (download speeds may be high enough but uploads are usually low) to send the video to the viewers. [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) makes it difficult to connect to a specific computer (from the public side there is only one IP for the computers under the router).